# Google Apps Script Rhino vs V8 Performance (343ms v 45,042ms)

Tags: google-apps-script, v8, rhino

I created a google apps script deployed as a web app executed as "user_deploying" and accessible by "anyone_anonymos".  Executing this with Rhino takes 343ms and executing this with V8 takes 45,042ms, as calculated at the Marks in the below code.  Why the difference and how can I increase the performance of V8, specifically Mark II?

Execution time averages in ms (rhino/V8):

- 227/497    Mark I - Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection()
- 112/44,497 Mark II - While(results.next()) {}
- 5/49       Mark III - close connections

the code:

```
// GET SCENARIO LIST
function getScenarioQuickList() {

  var start = new Date().getTime();

  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection('jdbc:google:mysql://...', user, userPwd);

  var query = 'SELECT a.`lvl`, a.`pubShort`, a.`scenTitle`, a.`pdfLink`';
    query += 'FROM `SA` a WHERE a.`scenId` <> "ZZZ99998" AND a.`scenId` <> "ZZZ99999" ORDER BY a.`scenId`;';
      
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  
  var results = stmt.executeQuery();
  
  var scenList = [];

  console.log(new Date().getTime()-start);  // mark 1
  
  // Push results to array

  start = new Date().getTime();

  while (results.next()) {
    scenList.push({
      'lvl': results.getString(1),
      'pubShort': results.getString(2),
      'scenTitle': results.getString(3),
      'pdfLink': results.getString(4),
    }); // close push
  } // close while
  
  console.log(new Date().getTime()-start); // mark 2

  start = new Date().getTime();

  results.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  
  console.log(new Date().getTime()-start); // mark 3

  return scenList;

}
```

Comment: A few other  users are having trouble with JDBC performance in V8 perhaps you should join the chorus and post it as an issue.

Comment: When I tried reproducing this, I only noticed a great performance difference when iterating through the [JdbcResultSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-result-set), via [next()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-result-set#next) in this case. Other actions, like attempting to connect or executing a query doesn't seem to show a significant difference (sometimes it's faster in V8, in my case). Can you please check if that's the case for you too? Or you've noticed it in other situations?

Comment: @lamblichus - after seeing the results above, i then switched six or seven of my Apps Script to Rhino and saw similar improvements.  I didn't need to test because the performance was obviously better.  I use them only on a Google Site and at least some were originally created using Rhino and later switched to V8.  Thanks, Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This might be a bug:

I have been able to reproduce this behavior for methods corresponding to [JdbcResultSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-result-set), especially when iterating through decent-sized results. The execution times in V8 are in many cases be much higher than in Rhino.

Interestingly, this seems to be intermittent, as sometimes the performance is similar.

#### Reported in Issue Tracker:

Taking all this into account, I have gone ahead and reported this behavior in Issue Tracker:

- [V8 performing worse than Rhino in JDBC service](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191684323)

Anyone affected by this, please consider [subscribing to this issue by starring it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of this and to help prioritizing it.